# Date column showing as "Date and Time" even though "Date Only" selected

Tags: list, date-time, field-type

In a workflow I have set up on a list, the email that is generated is showing a date with both date and time, with the time at 12:00:00 AM (using a lookup of one of the list's columns). Checking the source list, the column is of type Date, and the Date Format is set to "Date Only". Checking under the List Settings -> Column Types, the field's type shows as "Date and Time". Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like the issue is within your workflow "Add or Change Lookup" settings. When you add the Lookup, make sure you choose >> Current Item >> Column/Field Name >>"RETURN FIELD AS" -Here you can select "SHORT DATE" if you want the time to be removed.

Answer (score 0):

I have discovered a  simple way of formatting Date field in SharePoint to exclude time stamp.

I opened the list in SharePoint Designer and open the properties of the list. Select Formatting and deselect Time.